# How to use isin while ignoring index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to check if rows exist in another dataframe. I'm not joining/merging because of issues with it creating duplication, and then needing to filter out that duplication might also filter out actual duplication that I *want* to keep.

*example:*

```
table1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 5, 3, 4],
              'b':['a', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'd']})
table2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 4, 3, 6, 2],
              'b':['a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'b']})


table1.isin(table2)

       a      b
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
4  False  False
```

I would like all of these to be `True` except at index 2 where row `5 e` doesn't exist in `table2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC

```
table1.stack().isin(table2.stack().values).unstack()
Out[207]: 
       a      b
0   True   True
1   True   True
2  False  False
3   True   True
4   True   True
```

If check the row bases

```
table1.astype(str).sum(1).isin(table2.astype(str).sum(1))
```

By using `merge`

```
table1.merge(table2.assign(vec=True),how='left').fillna(False)
Out[232]: 
   a  b    vec
0  1  a   True
1  2  b   True
2  5  e  False
3  3  c   True
4  4  d   True
```

Comment: @MattW. yw :-) happy coding

Comment: Sorry, but it seems OP need your commented solution, what is really easy not recommended because very easy False positive. Need separator between.

Comment: @jezrael I mask a solution at the end :-)

Comment: Yes, I say about it, unfortunately generally very bad solution.

Comment: I try explain why if there is multiple columns then sum return fir each row one string and i

Comment: It can join 135 with 2 to 1352 and also 13 with 52 to same string, what is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If need compare each value separately convert `table2` to `1d` array:

```
a = table1.isin(table2.values.ravel())
print (a)
       a      b
0   True   True
1   True   True
2  False  False
3   True   True
4   True   True
```

If need compare each row separately:

```
a = (table1.apply(tuple, 1).isin(table2.apply(tuple, 1)))
```

Or:

```
a = (table1.astype(str).apply('###'.join, 1).isin(table2.astype(str).apply('###'.join, 1).))


print (a)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

For better explanation input data are changed:

```
table1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 5, 3, 4],
              'b':['d', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'd']})
table2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 4, 3, 6, 2],
              'b':['a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'b']})

print (table1)
   a  b
0  1  d -> changed to d
1  2  b
2  5  e
3  3  c
4  4  d

print (table2)
   a  b
0  1  a
1  4  d
2  3  c
3  6  f
4  2  b
```

---

```
a = table1.isin(table2.values.ravel())
print (a)
       a      b
0   True   True  d exist in table2, so True
1   True   True
2  False  False
3   True   True
4   True   True

a = (table1.apply(tuple, 1).isin(table2.apply(tuple, 1)))
print (a)
0    False -> comparing 1-a with 1-b return False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`. If you add in another row to table1 that doesn't exist in table2, it all falls apart, as should be a more representative dataset for what I'm working with. I'll edit the starting dataset

Comment: @MattW. - so need compare each value separately? Not each rows? Check edited answer.

Comment: It would be to compare entire rows. So ultimately once getting the table of trues and falses, I would add `.all(axis=1)`

Comment: So then need compare by tuples or with joined each rows. I try explain difference in changed input data.

Comment: The tuple version doesn't seem to work on my dataset. it returns a full boolean table instead of a vector

Comment: no it still isn't, the full boolean table isn't correct either. I like the idea of turning the rows into tuples and comparing, but I'm not sure its working.

Comment: @Matt W. Alternative solution also failed? Order of columns is same in both dataframes? Are data confidental? If not, I can check it, my email is in my profile.