# How to check if every line of one file is in another file Python

Tags: python, pandas

file1:

```
2018-06-07, AAA, 26543.0, 123, 0.0
2018-06-07, AAA, 26512.0, 123, 1.0
```

file2:

```
20180608, B, 12345, 343, 0
20180607, AAA, 26512, 123, 1
20180608, C, 123, 343, 0
20180607, AAA, 26543, 123, 0
```

Right now, I can figure out one way, for every line in file1, I simply process it and try to find the matched line in file2. However, this solution could potentially have some problems, since we deal with relatively large data, this method (algorithm) could be extremely slow.

1. I'm wondering if there is some Python built-in library that allows me to check this easily, like Pandas... (note: the data format, type for the second and last fields are different, but the data is the same)
2. If no library allows me to do this stuff directly, is there some better algorithm that allows me to achieve the goal?
   Thanks

Comment: Can you post your attempt so far?

Comment: almost same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645297/how-to-use-isin-while-ignoring-index/50645672#50645672

Comment: You'll have to first convert the dates (to the same format or something), but you can use `merge`, or concatenate them together and look for duplicates (if rows are distinct in each `df`)

Comment: @Wen Yeah, it actually is exactly the same problem and can be solved with exactly your solution, just adding a `.all(axis=1)` on the end of the `.unstack()`. Should probably mark as dup?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options available depending upon how large your `DataFrame`s are and exactly what you want.

First, get the dates to the same format using `pd.to_datetime`. Also ensure the columns are named the same in each `df`

```
import pandas as pd
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], format='%Y%m%d')

print(df1)
        date val1     val2  val3  val4
0 2018-06-07  AAA  26543.0   123   0.0
1 2018-06-07  AAA  26512.0   123   1.0

print(df2)
        date val1   val2  val3  val4
0 2018-06-08    B  12345   343     0
1 2018-06-07  AAA  26512   123     1
2 2018-06-08    C    123   343     0
3 2018-06-07  AAA  26543   123     0
```

---

## `pd.merge`

You can perform an `outer` merge with the `indicator` argument which then tells you which rows correspond to which `DataFrame`s.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
```

Outputs:

```
        date val1     val2  val3  val4      _merge
0 2018-06-07  AAA  26543.0   123   0.0        both
1 2018-06-07  AAA  26512.0   123   1.0        both
2 2018-06-08    B  12345.0   343   0.0  right_only
3 2018-06-08    C    123.0   343   0.0  right_only
```

The first two rows appear in both `df1` and `df2` while the bottom two rows only appear in `df2`. If you only care about shared rows, then just use an `inner` merge.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner')
        date val1   val2  val3 val4
0 2018-06-07  AAA  26543   123    0
1 2018-06-07  AAA  26512   123    1
```

## `duplicated`

If `df1` and `df2` do not contain any duplicated rows, then you can also just concatenate both and then look for duplicated rows in the concatenated `df` to see which are shared between both frames.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df[df.duplicated()]
```

Outputs:

```
        date val1     val2  val3  val4
1 2018-06-07  AAA  26512.0   123   1.0
3 2018-06-07  AAA  26543.0   123   0.0
```

Comment: A follow up. When I tried to merge two table according to all field in table one. If I use outer merge, it wont give me any "both" in _merge column. Let's say row zero, when pandas tries to merge, I guess the library consider 21543 and  21543.0 different. Any idea how to deal with this issue

Comment: @RickyZhou is the dtypes actually string or object for that column? `'21543'` will not match `'21543.0'` but if they are numeric they will match. Unless of course `21543` is really being stored as `21543.000000000000000000001`